# Parse Math Expression in PHP

Tags: parsing, math, expression, expression-trees, shunting-yard

I'm currently trying to parse math expression into expression tree.
But I'm stuck on the stage where I need to implement functions and negates. I don't understand logic to do it using Shunting-Yard algorithm.

What I currently want to do is to support

- Negates, like -(x+5)
- Function calls, like min(x,y)
- Power just after function name, like cos^2(x)
- Implicit multiplication, like 2x is same as 2*x
- Scientific notation
- Constants e and pi

Can somebody tell me hints how to implement this?

Answer (score 1):

An *working*, PSR-0 compatible implementation of the shunting yard algorithm can be found here: https://github.com/andig/php-shunting-yard/tree/dev.
It supports constants, custom functions etc.